# how to call completion block?

Tags: objective-c, swift

How do I call this Swift based completion block in ObjectiveC?

```
public var completionBlock: IMGLYEditorCompletionBlock?
public typealias IMGLYEditorCompletionBlock = (IMGLYEditorResult, UIImage?) -> Void
```

This is how I call it in Swift but never work in Objective C.

```
func callEditorViewController() {
   var editorViewController = IMGLYMainEditorViewController()
   editorViewController.highResolutionImage = image
   editorViewController.initialFilterType = .None
   editorViewController.initialFilterIntensity = 0.5
   editorViewController.completionBlock = editorCompletionBlock
}

func editorCompletionBlock(result: IMGLYEditorResult, image: UIImage?) {
   ...
}
```

This is my objective C code with syntax error.

```
-(void) editorCompletionBlock:(IMGLYEditorResult*)result img:(UIImage*)image{
```

}

```
 IMGLYMainEditorViewController *editor = [[IMGLYMainEditorViewController alloc]init];
editor.highResolutionImage = image;

 editor.completionBlock = [self editorCompletionBlock:r img:image];
```

Comment: There is no code calling it.

Comment: eiko, I added the call with syntax error.

Comment: Still unclear - are you asking how to set the block or how to call it?

Comment: i want to call it.. editor.completionBlock = [self editorCompletionBlock:r img:image];
 this is error out, dude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling blocks is straight forward:

```
editor.completionBlock(result, image);
```

Still feeling you'd rather like to set it:

```
editor.completionBlock = ^(IMGLYEditorResult result, UIImage *image) {
        // do something meaningful here 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

first create new type in .h file

```
typedef void (^TableViewCellConfigureBlock)(id cell, id item);
```

then define your block in .m file like this in viewDidLoad

```
TableViewCellConfigureBlock configureCell = ^(id cell, id object) {
            [cell configureCellForObject:object];
        };
```

and finally call it from somewhere

```
UITableViewCell *cell;
NSString *item = @"my test string";

self.configureCellBlock(cell, item);
```